# Android : retrieve all data from database and store in ArrayList<HasMap<String, String>>

Tags: android, database, arraylist, hashmap

I try to retrieve all data from database and put into arraylist of hasmap
but i get only the last record of table.
here is my code :

```
databaseAirport myDbHelper = new databaseAirport(this);
myDbHelper.open();
Cursor c = myDbHelper.selectAll();
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> dataList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
if(c!=null && c.moveToFirst())
        {
                do
            {
                map.put(KEY_ACODE, c.getString(5).toString());
                map.put(KEY_FNUM, c.getString(6).toString());
                map.put(KEY_STOP_1, c.getString(8).toString());
                map.put(KEY_FTIME, c.getString(7).toString());
                map.put(KEY_REMARK, c.getString(10).toString());
                map.put(KEY_REM_COM, c.getString(11).toString());
                dataList.add(map);
            }while(c.moveToNext());
        }
```

At the end, my dataList(map) retrieve the last record only...

Can anyone help me please..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move this line as follow: `HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();`

```
databaseAirport myDbHelper = new databaseAirport(this);
myDbHelper.open();

Cursor c = myDbHelper.selectAll();
HashMap<String, String> map;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> dataList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
if(c!=null ){
     c.moveToFirst();

             while(  cur.isAfterLast() == false )
            {
                map = new HashMap<String, String>(); // <---- moved here

                map.put(KEY_ACODE, c.getString(5).toString());
                map.put(KEY_FNUM, c.getString(6).toString());
                map.put(KEY_STOP_1, c.getString(8).toString());
                map.put(KEY_FTIME, c.getString(7).toString());
                map.put(KEY_REMARK, c.getString(10).toString());
                map.put(KEY_REM_COM, c.getString(11).toString());
                dataList.add(map);
                c.moveToNext();
            }
        }
```

Comment: I've tried to move like this, but it still retrieve only one row and loop until dataList.size();

Comment: I have 50 rows in my database

Comment: now it get the different row, but still get only one same data row..my query is ....select * from tbl_str...and there is 12 columns with 35 rows.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code like this

```
databaseAirport myDbHelper = new databaseAirport(this);
myDbHelper.open();
Cursor c = myDbHelper.selectAll();
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> dataList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
while(c.moveToNext());
{
     HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
     map.put(KEY_ACODE, c.getString(5).toString());
     map.put(KEY_FNUM, c.getString(6).toString());
     map.put(KEY_STOP_1, c.getString(8).toString());
     map.put(KEY_FTIME, c.getString(7).toString());
     map.put(KEY_REMARK, c.getString(10).toString());
     map.put(KEY_REM_COM, c.getString(11).toString());
     dataList.add(map);
}
```

Comment: No need to test this.More you can check if(c!=null).

Comment: Maybe something is wrong with your query. the code above should be ok.

Comment: i test it List<String> it work fine with my query... just select all data from table.